# Restart Python program if user input to 'run again?' is 'y'

Tags: python

```
while True:
# main program

    number = (" ")
total = 0

num1 = int(input("enter a number"))
total = total + num1
num2 = int(input("enter a number"))
total = total + num2
num3 = int(input("enter a number"))
total = total + num3

if total > 100:
    print("That's a big number!")
else:
    print("That's a small number.")
print(total)

while True:
        answer = raw_input("Run again? (y/n): ")
        if answer in y, n:
            break
        print("Invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print 'Goodbye'
        break
```

Essentially I want the program to restart when the user enters 'y' as a response to 'run again?' Any help would be vastly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try writing your main as a function (https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html) then call main() `if answer=='y'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @burhan suggested, simply wrap your main program inside a function. BTW, your code has some bugs which could use some help:

- `if answer in y, n:` - you probably mean `if answer not in ('y', 'n')`:
- `number = (" ")` is an irrelevant line
- `while True` makes no sense in your main program
- `print("Invalid input.")` is below a `break`, thus it'll never be executed

So you'll have something like:

```
def main():
    total = 0

    num1 = int(input("enter a number"))
    total = total + num1
    num2 = int(input("enter a number"))
    total = total + num2
    num3 = int(input("enter a number"))
    total = total + num3

    if total > 100:
        print("That's a big number!")
    else:
        print("That's a small number.")
    print(total)

while True:
    answer = raw_input("Run again? (y/n): ")
    if answer not in ('y', 'n'):
        print("Invalid input.")
        break
    if answer == 'y':
        main()
    else:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

Comment: You beat me to it, few imporvements though,
In `answer not in ('y', 'n')` I think he should use continue to give user another chance to input again and `main()` should be called once before while loop

Answer (score -1):

```
def main():
    total = 0
    num1 = int(input("enter a number"))
    total = total + num1
    num2 = int(input("enter a number"))
    total = total + num2
    num3 = int(input("enter a number"))
    total = total + num3

    if total > 100:
        print("That's a big number!")
    else:
        print("That's a small number.")
    print(total)

    answer = raw_input("Run again? (y/n): ")

    if answer not in ('y', 'n'):
        print("Invalid input.")
    if answer == 'y':
        main()
    else:
        print 'Goodbye'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You should probably add a few checks to handle cases when users enter non-number input etc.

Answer (score -2):

Your code looks really messed up. Try to write some better(clean) code next time.

```
while True:
    total = 0

    num1 = int(input("enter a number"))
    num2 = int(input("enter a number"))
    num3 = int(input("enter a number"))
    total = num1 + num2 + num3

    if total > 100:
        print("That's a big number!")
    else:
        print("That's a small number.")
    print(total)

    con = int(input("Run again? 1/0: "))
    if con==0:
        break
```

Comment: You didn't explain anything about what the problem was or what you did to fix it.

Comment: Yeah, my bad :) But I tried to give the simplest possible solution for the problem.

Comment: But it did solve my problem. I was required to use a while loop and wanted the program to rerun if the user wanted it to. So thanks to Muhammad Asif for helping. I would press the 'Answered' button but can't because this is a new account.

Comment: Glad to solve the problem :) Good Luck in learning python @WhiteTail

Comment: @MuhammadAsif there is still an issue: if I enter '0' the program reruns as if I typed '1'

Comment: @WhiteTail there was a syntax error. On line "con = int(in..........)"     there was a semi-colon at the end. I've removed it now. Now check the code.

Comment: Great to know that :)